# Docker Swarm Deployment Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger

I am facing an issue with docker swarm .I am trying to deploy a network over AWS using docker swarm .All of my services are working and running fine after docker deploy stack command.

I have two AWS instances. I deploy orderer and 2 peer of an organisation on first AWS instance. On the other side 2 peer of another organisation has been deployed on second AWS instance with cli also.
All the service running on instance 1 is able to communicate each other .And all the services on instance 2 are able to communicate each other . But if i try to connect any service from other instance then no luck.

ANy idea what is happening there..

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below Github repo, it should help you to understand better how to implement Docker swarm in hyperledger Fabric

https://github.com/sebastianpaulp/Balance_Transfer_Docker_Swarm